# LINQ IQueryable to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get data from 3 tables using LINQ to return an `IEnumerable<PortalUser>` but not having much luck. When I want to return the result, it is of type `IQueryable<PortalUser>` and I'm not sure what I should be doing in order to achieve my goal:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<PortalUser>> GetUsers(string accountCode)
{
    var res = from u in _db.Users
              join ur in _db.UserRoles on u.ContactGuid equals ur.ContactGuid
              join r in _db.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
              where ur.AccountCode == accountCode
              select(new PortalUser(u.Id, u.FriendlyName, u.UserName, r.RoleName));
    return res;
}
```

In my select, I try to use the `PortalUser` constructor to make PortalUsers and thought this would give me what I wanted but clearly not.

```
public class PortalUser
{
    public PortalUser(int id,string friendlyName,string username,string rolename)
    {
        Id = id.ToString();
        Firstname = friendlyName.Split(' ')[0];
        Lastname = friendlyName.Split(' ')[1];
        Username = username;
        Role = rolename;
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Linq.IQueryable<BSAR.Services.Models.Outbound.Full.PortalUser>'` to `'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskSystem.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<BSAR.Services.Models.Outbound.Full.PortalUser'>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message?  It's expecting a `Task`, but you're not providing a `Task`.  You can't do that.

Comment: Can you change the return type? If not, why don't you mark the method `async` and `return await res.ToListAsync()`? What are you _really_ trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Doing what CodeCaster suggested "Can you change the return type? If not, why don't you mark the method async and return await res.ToListAsync()? What are you really trying to do?"

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<PortalUser>> GetUsers(string accountCode)
    {
        var res = from u in _db.Users
                  join ur in _db.UserRoles on u.ContactGuid equals ur.ContactGuid
                  join r in _db.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
                  where ur.AccountCode == accountCode
                  select (new PortalUser(u.Id, u.FriendlyName, u.UserName, r.RoleName));
        return await res.ToListAsync();
    }
```

this resolved my issue thank you

Answer (score 0):

`GetUsers` doesn't return a task - therefore you have to change the return type to `IEnumerable<PortalUser>`:

```
public IEnumerable<PortalUser> GetUsers(string accountCode)
{
    var res = from u in _db.Users
        join ur in _db.UserRoles on u.ContactGuid equals ur.ContactGuid
        join r in _db.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
        where ur.AccountCode == accountCode
        select (new PortalUser(u.Id, u.FriendlyName, u.UserName, r.RoleName));
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for quick response i see now what was wrong will accept answer as soon as i can

Comment: @mjmendes I'd advise against accepting answers that don't actually work, as it will simply cause grief to future readers who come across the solution and may be tricked into thinking it's a working solution.

Comment: @MetaColon Try to run the code and see for yourself.

Comment: @Servy It's rather hard to run the code as it uses different classes, I'd have to replace with dummy classes. But if you can't tell me what's wrong with the code, I'll try this.

Comment: @Servy As it happens, it works with dummy classes. Maybe you forgot to add those?

Comment: @MetaColon It *compiles*.  It doesn't *do* anything.  Turning a compile time error into a runtime bug is *worse*, as it's *less* visible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146447/discussion-between-metacolon-and-servy).